# GWT DateBox Format

Tags: java, gwt

I want to set format to DateBox in GWT.

Format required is `dd/MM/yyyy`.

I tried using:

```
DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dateBoxObj.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(dateFormat));
```

Any Help??

Comment: You tried correctly. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Cross check which DateTimeFormat you imported...Use this com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat...its looking like the above code should work...
I too have used this DatetimeFormat... like this

```
Date date = event.getValue(); //Date from Selection
String dateString = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);
textbox.setValue(dateString); //this date is in form of "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But its setting the format as yyyy/MM/dd though i have set the format as dd/MM/yyyy